# Activity orientation is inherited from parent

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I have an Android application with 2 activities (actually more, but it doesnt matter here).

The 1st one has fixed orientation (landsape) and the 2nd one has default (undefined) orientation. The 1st activity acts as a splash screen then starts 2nd activity automatically.

The problem is 2nd activity inherits landscape orientation from the 1st one, i.e. if device orientation is vertical when 2nd activity appears it has landscape orientation then immediately rotates to vertical one.

If I remove the 1st activity so that the 2nd one appears during start it doesnt happen.

Note I can neither set vertical orientation for the 1st activity nor set undefined orientation and draw accordingly for some reason.

Please help.

`<activity android:name="SplashActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="screenSize"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="GameActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                  android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
        </activity>`

I also tried using 'undefined' or not to set any orientation at all for GameActivity.

Comment: Hm... Is auto-rotate enabled?

Comment: How did you lock the orientation ?  manifest or code ? please post it

Comment: @Max yes, of course - auto-rotate is enabled for the 2nd activity, the problem is the orientation is wrong when its shown, but rotates immediately to correct.

Comment: @ShaiLevy Manifest, please see updated question.

Comment: @Anton Oh. That behaviour is just Android right now, we can't do anything against it (except doing it with code)

Comment: @Max Could you please advise how to overcome it using the code? Do you mean if I request specific orientation programmatically, the problem doesnt reproduce? There is no explicit requirement to fix orientation in Manifest, it just has to be fixed using any avaliable way.

Comment: @Anton Well, first I have to know: Why is your game rotateable?

Comment: @Max its board game - so while the board remains roughly on the same place the controls (buttons etc) change their places depending on the orientation to optimally utilize free space.

Comment: @Anton Hm... How about setting a predefined orientation in onCreate? I'll show you some code, wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got it right. So you want, that the second `Activity` doesn't get the rotation of the first one.

Use the following inside the `onCreate()` method in the second `Activity`:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

If it still doesn't help, then it's just Android's behaviour.
If it helped, it's good.

After the `Intent` **in the first** `Activity`, which should look like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
startActivity(spcthxopen);
```

You just put

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

under that `Intent`. I just tried it and it perfectly workarounds Android's default behaviour.

Comment: @Anton I just edited my answer. I tried some things and found one workaround for Android's default behaviour.